# Question about loading tensor for calculating the rmse

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

currenly I am buidling a Deep Learning model to train some data. However, while loading the data from the data loader and model to the take the label and data for the rmse calculation, it seems like I have the error

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/ipykernel_6877/1236871952.py", line 45, in train self.train_epoch(epoch) File "/tmp/ipykernel_6877/1236871952.py", line 20, in train_epoch x_tensor = x.float().to(self.device) AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to'`

It seems like the problem lying on whether my Dataloader class or Dataloader loading process that cause this error. Here is the class for Dataloader:

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, config, x_path, y_path):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config
        self.x_path = x_path
        self.y_path = y_path
        self.load_dataset()
def __len__(self):
    return self.data_.shape[0]

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    input_tensor = torch.from_numpy(self.data_[idx]).float()
    label_tensor = torch.from_numpy(np.array(self.labels[idx])).float()
    return {'input': input_tensor, 'labels': label_tensor}

def load_dataset(self):
    x_data = {}
    y_data = {}
    x_path_ = os.path.join(self.config['data_dir'], self.x_path)
    y_path_ = os.path.join(self.config['data_dir'], self.y_path)

    with h5py.File(x_path_, 'r') as x_file:
        x_data_key = list(x_file.keys())[0]
        x_data['data'] = np.array(x_file[x_data_key])
 
    with h5py.File(y_path_, 'r') as y_file:
        y_data_key = list(y_file.keys())[0]
        y_data['label'] = np.array(y_file[y_data_key])
        
    self.data_ = x_data['data'].transpose(1,0)
    self.data_ = np.expand_dims(self.data_, axis=0)
    self.labels = y_data['label']
    self.config['data_shape'] = self.data_.shape[1:]
    
    # Convert to tensors
    #self.data_ = torch.tensor(self.data_).float()
    #self.labels = torch.tensor(self.labels).float()
def getshape(self):
        return self.config['data_shape']
```

and the Error occurs in the following:

```
def train_epoch(self, epoch):
    train_loss = 0.0
    self.model.train()
    for x, rul in enumerate(self.train_data):
        self.model.zero_grad()
        out = self.model(x.to(self.device).float())
        loss = torch.sqrt(self.criterion(out.float(), rul.to(self.device).float())) # RMSE
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss
```

Here is the loading process. Given that the train_data method is used via Dataloader method to load the data through class CustomDataset and loaded with the batch_size of 128. One thing I know is that I have tested loading the data through class CustomDataset and it still returns tensor as a result, so how can I deal with this problem ?

Comment: `'int' object has no attribute 'to'` is a straightforward error. Are you sure that `x`  and `rul` are tensors?

Comment: @Josmy thank you, I have found the solution. Turn out I have to use i, (x,rul) instead of x,rul so that it will return tensors straight forward